# CD/Drive not Reading Disc

Tags: cd-drive

Ubuntu Trusty Tahr, I've thrown a computer together from scratch for the first time and I'm currently trying to install a CD drive so i can read disc. Ive tried many methods but just cant seem to get it to work, I've tried wodim and another method "add CD Rom" I've got to the point to when i open the application "DISKS" the CD drive finally under my devices tab mounted in `/dev/sr0` (read only). but says it has no media in the drive which it does. if you can help tat would be great thanks, not really sure where to go from here.

```
apt-cdrom add
Using CD-ROM mount point /media/cdrom/
Unmounting CD-ROM...
Waiting for disc...
Please insert a Disc in the drive and press enter 
Mounting CD-ROM...
E: Failed to mount the cdrom.
E: No CD-ROM could be auto-detected or found using the default mount point.
You may try the --cdrom option to set the CD-ROM mount point.
See 'man apt-cdrom' for more information about the CD-ROM auto-detection and mount point.
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1) Try another media - the one you are using may be scratched beyond readability

Step 2) Clean it. Dust on the laser can cause this. You can blow it off with canned air.

Step 3) Replace it with a known working drive.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the CD Drive itself is faulty. As for now, it might be a hardware issue. 
What I would do is try to re-start the computer with an installation Ubuntu Live CD and if the computer manages to boot up into the Live CD, then you know that the CD Drive works.  Once we know the drive works then we can continue looking for a problem on the software end of things.

Comment: ok well its brand new so i hope thats not the issue, i dont have an ubuntu live disk so i might have to order one. i looked closer and saw this as the mnt point /mnt/ata-ATAPI_DVD_A_DH16A1L,  i really just think i might have mixed up on the mounting

Comment: If it's new, then shutdown your pc, then unplug the CD Drive and re-connect it, then restart Ubuntu and without changing anything else, try to put in a disc again.  Also, maybe try putting in a disc that already has something in it to see if it can be read properly.